# EF code-first doesn't create all tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, entity-framework, xsd

I'm trying to create my tables based on a class file generated from an XSD.

But not all XML information is being entered in the database. What could be happening?

XML example: http://pastebin.com/HthQBzQL

---

**UPDATE XSD FILE:**

My classes from XSD: http://pastebin.com/SvuzK4i6

---

My EF context :

```
public class NFeContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TNfeProc> TNfeProc { get; set; }
}
```

---

Code that serialize XML and insert into Sql Server Database:

```
var db = new NFeContext();
db.Database.CreateIfNotExists();

Stream reader = new FileStream(@"C:\XML\file1.xml", FileMode.Open);
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TNfeProc));
TNfeProc XML = (TNfeProc)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

XML.NFe.infNFe.transp.retTransp = (XML.NFe.infNFe.transp.retTransp == null) ? new TNFeInfNFeTranspRetTransp() : XML.NFe.infNFe.transp.retTransp;           
XML.NFe.infNFeSupl = (XML.NFe.infNFeSupl == null) ? new TNFeInfNFeSupl() : XML.NFe.infNFeSupl;
XML.NFe.infNFe.avulsa = (XML.NFe.infNFe.avulsa == null) ? new TNFeInfNFeAvulsa() : XML.NFe.infNFe.avulsa;
XML.NFe.infNFe.retirada = (XML.NFe.infNFe.retirada == null) ? new TLocal() : XML.NFe.infNFe.retirada;
XML.NFe.infNFe.entrega = (XML.NFe.infNFe.entrega == null) ? new TLocal() : XML.NFe.infNFe.entrega;
XML.NFe.infNFe.exporta = (XML.NFe.infNFe.exporta == null) ? new TNFeInfNFeExporta() : XML.NFe.infNFe.exporta;
XML.NFe.infNFe.compra = (XML.NFe.infNFe.compra == null) ? new TNFeInfNFeCompra() : XML.NFe.infNFe.compra;
XML.NFe.infNFe.cana = (XML.NFe.infNFe.cana == null) ? new TNFeInfNFeCana() : XML.NFe.infNFe.cana;
XML.NFe.infNFe.total.ISSQNtot = (XML.NFe.infNFe.total.ISSQNtot == null) ? new TNFeInfNFeTotalISSQNtot() : XML.NFe.infNFe.total.ISSQNtot;
XML.NFe.infNFe.total.retTrib = (XML.NFe.infNFe.total.retTrib == null) ? new TNFeInfNFeTotalRetTrib() : XML.NFe.infNFe.total.retTrib;

db.TNfeProc.Add(XML);           


db.SaveChanges();
```

What remains set to get input all XML information in the database?

**EDIT**

An example of information that is not entering is **det** node

[image]

---

Here is the tables created by my code:

[image]

Why not create the **TNFeInfNFeDets** Table and others tables?

Examble Debug of **det** property

[image]

Comment: Please post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) --this is way too much code. Also, post it in the question itself. And be more specific about *not all XML information*.

Comment: Can you specify which sections aren't importing?  there are some private objects that were generated in the classes.  Only Public objects will deserialize.  So you may need to change the private objects to public.

Comment: I edited my post with new information